# POutput cannot be converted to WriteResult

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I'm trying to follow [KafkaToBigQuery's DataflowTemplates](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/10135ce0e50f4a77faf73f632931db3e2171ff28/v2/kafka-to-bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/templates/KafkaToBigQuery.java#L287) to handle BigQuery's error in my code.

```java
PCollection convertedTableRows =
            pipline
                .apply("ReadFromKafka", buildReadToKafkaIO(options))
                .apply("ConvertMessageToTableRow", new.TransformTableRow());

WriteResult writeResult = convertedTableRows.apply("WriteRecords", 
            BigQueryIO.writeTableRows());
//          ...

writeResult.getFailedInsertsWithErr()
            .apply("WrapInsertionErrors", MapElements.into(TypeDescriptors.strings())
                                            .via(ClassName::wrapBigQueryInsertError));
```

While compile, I got error: `org.apache.beam.sdk.values.POutput cannot be converted to org.apache.beam.sdk.io.gcp.bigquery.WriteResult`

I can understood this error, due to [Class WriteResult](https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.20.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/gcp/bigquery/WriteResult.html) say it implements POutput.

So, At [KafkaToBigQuery's DataflowTemplates](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowTemplates/blob/10135ce0e50f4a77faf73f632931db3e2171ff28/v2/kafka-to-bigquery/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/teleport/v2/templates/KafkaToBigQuery.java#L287) somewhere override apply method can return WriteResult?

Answer (score 1):

It seems there is a missed invocation of `.to()` method.

See template's example:

```
    WriteResult writeResult =
        convertedTableRows
            .get(TRANSFORM_OUT)
            .apply(
                "WriteSuccessfulRecords",
                BigQueryIO.writeTableRows()
                    .withoutValidation()
                    .withCreateDisposition(CreateDisposition.CREATE_NEVER)
                    .withWriteDisposition(WriteDisposition.WRITE_APPEND)
                    .withExtendedErrorInfo()
                    .withMethod(BigQueryIO.Write.Method.STREAMING_INSERTS)
                    .withFailedInsertRetryPolicy(InsertRetryPolicy.retryTransientErrors())
                    .to(options.getOutputTableSpec()));
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks boden.
In fact, I omitted part of the code.

I rechecked Transform.TransformTableRow()， make sure it return TableRow.

`PCollection<TableRow>` looks very important.

```java
PCollection<TableRow> convertedTableRows = inputFromKafka.apply("transform",
  ParDo.of(new Transform.TransformTableRow()));

WriteResult writeResultToBigQuery = convertedTableRows
                 .apply("writeToBigQuery", buildWriteTableRowsToBigQueryIO(options));
```